# How do I create an Instagram account in a desktop browser?

Tags: instagram

How do I create an Instagram account on my computer? I have the app but it says I have created too many accounts.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot.**

From the [Instagram help page](https://help.instagram.com/182492381886913/):

> You must create your account using the Instagram mobile app, not a computer.